# ANTLR Simplification

Tags: java, antlr

I would like to get an ANLR grammar able to matche the following expressions

```
C_03
C 03
C03
```

This grammar works

```
template_reference
    : template_label template_number
    ;

template_number
    : INT
    ;

template_label
    : 'A '|'B '|'C '|'D ' .... other letters up to Z
    | 'A_'|'B_'|'C_'|'D_' .... other letters up to Z
    | 'A' |'B' |'C' |'D' .... other letters up to Z
    ;
```

but I would like to simplify it (not having all letters from A to Z)

Comment: Just use regex to include all cap letters, `[A-Z]` perhaps give it a label `CAPS : [A-Z];`. But your actual grammatical requirements are somewhat unclear, since your working grammar doesn't appear to match your text to match.

Comment: or `\p{Lu}` for more than English letters

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, `[A-Z]` matches uppercase (ascii) letters. But you must use `[A-Z]` inside a lexer rule, not a parser rule (like `template_label`).

Try this:

```
template_reference
 : TEMPLATE_LABEL INT
 ;

TEMPLATE_LABEL
 : [A-Z] [_ ]? // or [\p{Lu}] for all uppercase letters
 ;

INT
 : [0-9]+
 ;
```

Comment: Ok now I see my mistake. I’ll update my grammar and post the result after

Answer (score 0):

Use `[A-Z]` as a token to match all capital letters.